# Sqoop job failure notification

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

Consider I have configured 10 sqoop jobs. How would I get to know if one of them failed? Is there any configuration in sqoop for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an oozie workflow for this usecase. Create a java action for sending emails in case of failure. 
You can write a small java program to send email with required messages and call this through the Java action.

Comment: Oozie provides an email action.

Answer (score 0):

@divinedragon You can put all your sqoop jobs in a shell script and write a small code to send the failure status. Failure status mailing Shell code looks like this:

defining email function

```
email_func_fail()
{
    mail -s "FAILED: Status job failed for date" -c "${CC_LIST}" "$TO_ADDRESS" < ${log_file}
}
```

after each job, check for the failed status. if the job is failed then send an email

```
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
        email_func_fail
        exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run a sqoop job, it gives you a MapReduce jobid; something like "application_job_1500540444935_0302" which you can look at in your resourcemanager. Hadoop resourcemanager also provides RestApi to query status of your job.

The RestApi is- "http://ResourceManagerIP:ResourceManagerPort (8088 usually)/ws/v1/cluster/apps/(job_id)"

You can use this api to get status of your job.